# Error while changing aes mode of aes in mysql: Unknown system variable 'block_encryption_mode'

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

I wants to change AES encryption mode to OFB from DEFAULT ECB, I executed following query to change mode:

```
SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-ofb'
```

This gives following error:

```
 #1193 - Unknown system variable 'block_encryption_mode'
```

Can anyone let me know what's wrong I am doing?

Comment: As the documentation specifies:  "This variable was added in MySQL 5.7.4.".

Comment: @GordonLinoff 5.6.17; 5.7.4

Comment: So can you let me know how I can change aes mode on version 5.6.16

Answer (score 3):

block_encryption_mode system variable added in MySQL 5.6.17
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-17.html

You can not change the block encryption mode in previous versions.